# I get an exception during deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I get this message when running the code below:

> There is an error in XML document (6, 22).

```
namespace N1
{
    public class InputEntry
    {
        //FieldName is a class tht is generated from an XSD which has complex type Name and value
        private Field fields;
        public Field[] Fields
        {
            get { return this.fields; }
            set { this.fields= value; }
        }

        public string FieldName
        {
           get{return this.fieldName;}
           set { this.fieldName = value; }
        }

       public string FieldValue
       {
        get {return this.fieldValue; }
        set {this.fieldValue = value;}
       }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            InputEntry inputEntry = new InputEntry();
            //we some how get the values from user and assign them to
            Field f1 = new Field();
            f1.FieldName = "PRINTLINE00";
            f1.FieldValue = "DENIAL STATE" ;
        }

        private void Method2(InputEntry inputEntry)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(InputEntry));
            System.IO.StringWriter inputStr = new System.IO.StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            serializer.Serialize(inputStr, inputEntry);
            string ipEntry = inputStr.ToString();
            Method3(ipEntry);
        }

        private void Method3(string ipEntry)
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(InputEntry));
            System.IO.StringReader inputStr = new System.IO.StringReader(ipEntry);
            InputEntry inputEntry = (InputEntry)serializer.Deserialize(inputStr);

        }
    }
}
     // when client configues input data as
     // <FieldName>PRINTLINE00</FieldName> <FieldValue>DENIAL STATE</FieldValue>,
     //I get an exception when the same data deserialised
     //Exception is:-
```

String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<InputEntry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Fields>
    <Field>
      <FieldName>PRINTLINE00</FieldName>
      <FieldValue>&#x1B;DENIAL STATE 217</FieldValue>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
</InputEntry>
```

Comment: Can you reformat your question please? The XML document seems to have been lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off character checking, something like this:

```
serializer.Deserialize (XmlReader.Create (inputStr, new XmlReaderSettings
    { CheckCharacters = false, }))
```

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the fact that you're missing a closing Fields tag, you've also tried to serialise Unicode character U+001B... which unfortunately isn't supported in XML.

That's an "escape" character... did you really want it in the string to start with? It could be that you can just add validation (or trimming) in your code.

Comment: please ignore all those fromatting, everthing is well formed

Comment: I want to know if StringWriter and UTF16 has some prob related to this exception. any other way we can Encoding would solve this prob

Comment: Jon, U+001B might not be supported by XML, but [it is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.checkcharacters.aspx) by .NET's XML serializer.

Comment: @Anton: True (and I didn't know that before - why did you delete your answer). I would suggest that creating invalid XML isn't a great idea though :(

Comment: Can you please suggest a way where i can serialize something of type String and i dont get such exception(beacuse of the escape chars) and also have a handle on the type i.e., use UTF-8 rather than the defaultly generated UTF-16

Comment: @starz26: As Anton suggested, you *could* set XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters to false when you deserialize, but then you end up with invalid XML. To generate UTF-8 instead of UTF-16, you need to use a StringWriter which advertises itself as being UTF-8 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564718/using-stringwriter-for-xml-serialization/1564727#1564727

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing `</Fields>` tag in your xml document.

Comment: But why would XmlSerializer  omit the `</Fields>` tag when serializing the `InputEntry` instance?

Comment: it was some mistake while i was posting question. Now everything is updated

Answer (score 0):

```
<FieldName>PRINTLINE00</FieldName> <FieldValue**>**DENIAL STATE</FieldValue>
```

missing an <

Comment: I assumed that was a typo and fixed it... maybe I shouldn't have