# Setting StandAlone = Yes in .Net when serializing an object

Tags: .net, serialization, xml-serialization

In the following code I want to set "standalone = yes" to the xml, how can I do this?

```
Dim settings As New Xml.XmlWriterSettings
settings.Encoding = encoding

Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream, xtWriter As Xml.XmlWriter = _
    Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)
    serializer.Serialize(xtWriter, obj)
    Return encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray())
End Using
```

For example, I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But I want this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do this then you'll need to use [`WriteProcessingInstruction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeprocessinginstruction.aspx) method and manually write it out.

```
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream, xtWriter As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)
        xtWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""")
        serializer.Serialize(xtWriter, obj)
        Return encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray())
    End Using
```

Comment: Thank you, that's still not as elegant as I would have hoped, but it is still better than .Replace("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>", "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?>"). lol

Comment: You can use xmlriter.WriteStartDocument(true);

Comment: @HasaniBlackwell ugh, just now I notice that comment....... that would have been the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 22):

I've found a much more elegant way of doing this: simply call `WriteStartDocument(true)` on your `XmlWriter` instance - this code serializes `data` and outputs the resulting XML to console.

First, if you're using a `StringWriter` you need to tweak it a bit to force UTF-8, but [keep this in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564803/1188513):

> *When serialising an XML document to a .NET string, the encoding must be set to UTF-16. Strings are stored as UTF-16 internally, so this is the only encoding that makes sense. If you want to store data in a different encoding, you use a byte array instead.*

```
public sealed class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
}
```

```
using (var sw = new Utf8StringWriter())
using (var xw= XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings{Indent = true}))
{
    xw.WriteStartDocument(true); // that bool parameter is called "standalone"

    var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xw, data);

    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
}
```

`WriteStartDocument(true)` really feels like the idiomatic way of specifying `standalone=true`. The output heading looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Comment: Perhaps `xw.WriteStartDocument(standalone:=true)` would be a good use of named args?

Comment: In this code example, looks like 'namespaces' variable as a 3rd parameter to Serialize function was missed? I think xmlSerializer.Serialize(xw, data) should be changed to xmlSerializer.Serialize(xw, data, namespaces) if you want name spaces to be removed. Thanks.

Comment: @DiwakarPadmaraja possibly - the variable seems useless.... but the serialization works as intended as-is anyway.