# Write XML in Base64 encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml, base64

Following my questions about storing data, it has been suggested that I could use XML but then obfuscate the file by encoding it using Base64. I like this idea, and I have achieved what I want in XML, but I don't know how to save it in Base64. This is my code so far:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

XmlWriter write = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\Users\\Andy\\Desktop\\database.xml", settings);
write.WriteStartDocument();
write.WriteStartElement("Database");
write.WriteStartElement("Entry");
write.WriteAttributeString("key", "value");
write.WriteEndElement();
write.WriteEndElement();

write.Flush();
write.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
//..settings
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
{
    //...
}
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564718/using-stringwriter-for-xml-serialization
var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(); 
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));

File.WriteAllText("c:\temp.txt", s);
```

Read it:

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp.txt");
byte[] toDecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(readText);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(toDecodeByte))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        //.. read your xml
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to encode the entire XML file though, so could you please expand on that part.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the edit. So would I then just use a writer object to write `s` to a file? Also, I know I didn't ask it originally but could you show me how to read the XML file as well please?

Comment: @Andy the fastest way is to use System.IO.File.WriteAllText

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to C# and I'm still learning. Could you show me how to reverse that process and get the `XmlReader` object please?

Comment: This wont compile: `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Please do not use `ASCIIEncoding`. You should use `UTF8Encoding`.

Comment: @giammin Thanks very much. Just what I was after, but yeah, I'm not going to use `ASCIIEncoding` :) May I just ask if there is a reason you don't use a `MemoryStream` when writing the file?

Comment: @Andy you have to use ASCIIEncoding because base64 is ASCII. File.WriteAllText is shorter to write and internally it uses a streamwriter :D

Comment: @giammin Ah ok, that's fair enough. Could the same method be used for UTF8? Do I actually need UTF8?

Comment: @Andy sorry I made a mistake: base64 is Ascii but we are reading a string before converting to base64! in xml is better UTF16

Comment: @Andy about utf16, xml and c# string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564718/using-stringwriter-for-xml-serialization

Comment: @giammin So, if you are converting UTF16 to ASCII/Base64, does that mean that only characters in the ASCII character set can be supported?

Comment: You're right: base64 is ASCII and there's no need to use UTF8 encoding. No reason not too, either. But I was wrong to criticize your use of ASCII here. My apologies.

Comment: @JimMischel Will the method above mean that Unicode (non-ASCII) characters can't be included in the XML file though?

Comment: @Andy: You CAN include non-ASCII characters in the XML, regardless of whether you use ASCII or UTF8 when writing the base64 string. As was pointed out, base64 encodes binary data using only ASCII characters--that's the whole point of it. When it's decoded, you get back the original binary data.

Comment: @Andy sorry, I was out. Jim is right. Base64 encoding will handle non ascii chars.

Comment: @JimMischel  The only downside to use Utf8 encoding for a base64 string is that you waste a bit for every char.. we can live with that :D

Comment: It's ok. No problem. So will encoding the file significantly increase the size of the XML file? Does the amount it affects the file size increase with the original size of the file?

Comment: @Andy not significantly. don't understand the second question

Comment: @giammin I mean, if the file is larger when it isn't encoded, will encoding impact the size more than it would do a smaller XML file? i.e is the amount encoding affects a file size proportionate to the non-encode file size?

Comment: @giammin: UTF8 and ASCII would give the same size output for a base64 encoded string.

Comment: @Andy: base64 requires 4 characters to encode every 3 bytes. The encoded file will be larger than the original file. The encoded size will be `(4 * original_size)/3`.

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. One more question: how much extra time does it take to encode data? It may seem a strange comparison, but would it be any faster than compression?

Comment: @JimMischel yes, I meant that if you encode a file in utf8 instead of ascii for a base64 content you 'll have a little bigger file

Comment: @Andy imho compression is always slower but never tested it

Comment: @Andy: Compression and/or any non-trivial encryption (anything beyond a simple substitution cipher) will be slower than base64 encoding. base64 encoding is a very simple transformation. It will take longer to write the encoded string to disk than it takes to encode the string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your xmlwriter to string like this

```
 using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
 using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw)) {
// Build Xml with xw.


   }
  return sw.ToString();
}
```

then convert your string to Base64. and write it to file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I would I then have to create a new writer object for the Base64 encoded data?

Comment: +1. You should add the code that shows how to convert the returned string to base64 and write it to file.

Comment: @EhsanUllah Yes, please do :)

Comment: @EhsanUllah Yeah I have now thank you. It's ok, thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

This will have the information that you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writebase64.aspx

HTH,

d3

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to encode the entire XML file rather than just the values.

Comment: That's only good for writing specific binary data. That won't base64 encode the entire XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)

Save the XML data using MemoryStream to base64 encode the data and write it to a file.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{   
    // Memory Stream
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms,settings)) 
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Database");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Entry");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("key", "value");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();

        // XML Data (Debug)
        Console.WriteLine(new UTF8Encoding().GetString(ms.ToArray()));

        // Pre encoding hex (Debug)
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(ms.ToArray()));

        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(s); // (Debug)

        // Post encoding
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\A.enc", s);
    }
}
```

Read the file back

```
// Read encoded file back to xml
string enc_text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\A.enc");
Console.WriteLine(enc_text); // (Debug)

// Pre encoding hex
byte[] mem_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(enc_text);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(mem_bytes)); // (Debug)

// XML Data
Console.WriteLine(new UTF8Encoding().GetString(mem_bytes));

// Read byte array into Reader
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(mem_bytes))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        // Use reader as desired
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Regarding reading the file back, how could I actually get the data in the XmlReader rather than just print it? Which `Stream` object would be best to use?

Comment: @Andy - I updated to show how to create the XmlReader from the byte array data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it would be something like that, but I'm very new to C#.