# php xml SimpleXMLElement addChild big data breaking xml

Tags: php, xml, pdf

I am trying to insert base64_encoded pdf content in xml with below code.

1) Getting **pdf** data in variable.

> $varFilePath = 'temp_invoices/' . $varFileName;
>
> $arrFileData = **file_get_contents**($varFilePath);
>
> $varPdfBase64 = **base64_encode**($arrFileData);

2) Using base64 data in xml tag

> $Attachment->addChild('Attachment',  $varPdfBase64);

The variable **$varPdfBase64** has too big content and its creating problem.

Now when I am trying to download xml file this is showing **plain text** instead downloading with xml tags.

Note:- All tags are present in source code(ctrl+u).

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I know it's not the response, but this post maybe can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835928/write-xml-in-base64-encoding you can encode a part or all your xml with this method.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Are you using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or something else?

Comment: I add in title, I am using SimpleXmlElement :)

Comment: Maybe with this : $Attachment->addChild('Attachment', '<![CDATA[' . $varPdfBase64. ']]>');

Comment: I think the problem is with `'Attachment'`, that does not look like valid HTML to me. No browser will recognize the tag and the PDF will be rendered as plain text with the rest of the HMTL. Instead you should use an anchor tag `a` with a `href` attribute that links to the binary PDF file, or do something fun with JavaScript.

Comment: @Code4R7, No this is not an issue. We can use own tag in xml

Comment: @Shim-Sao, I have checked with CDATA but this does not work. This just add with text.

Comment: As per new rule, I need to send annexed pdf with electronic invoice.

Comment: Then I don't get the problem I think. You create an XML file with a base64 encoded attribute, and it won't be interpreted as XML by.. which application? Perhaps the XML result is invalid, or you forgot to add a HTTP Content Type, or have a wrong encoding? Does it work with smaller attachments?

Comment: @Code4R7, I am creating xml with SimpleXMLElement() function successfully. I need to add pdf content(base64 encoded) with the xml.

Comment: Base64 encoded content creating issue. On removing this tag this is working fine.

Comment: Me too, how do you open/interpret your xml ? HTTP, javascript... have nothing to do with XML, it is not the question. There is character issue on the encoding that break XML I think. Have you try to validate it ? https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: You set me on the wrong track by mentioning that the PDF was too big and it (therefore?) caused a problem, and you also mentioned that you weren't able to download something. As the XML appears as plain text the most likeliky result is that the XML markup is invalid, cause by that one line of code. Have you checked if the output XML is valid, by means of an XML validator?

Comment: @Code4R7, I mean base64 encoded text creating issue with XML. I try to validate xml but showing some error because of attchment tag text.  Error:-     The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: All the explanation for this error here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed