# How to generate this XML sample, with custom 2nd line, from within C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to generate the following XML, but have thus far been unsuccessful in injecting my custom header data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req xmlns:ns0="http://hsd.sd.com">
   <personnel_id>1202</personnel_id>
   <dob>19470906</dob>
</ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req>
```

How can i generate the above XML, from within C#?

Currently we have :

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
    StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, employee);
```

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string personnel_id { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some reasonable guesses about what your `Employee` class looks like, you need to do the following:

1. Decorate your `Employee` class with [`[XmlRoot("MT_Get_Name_Req", Namespace = "http://hsd.sd.com")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This will give your XML root element the correct name and namespace.
2. While the root is in the `http://hsd.sd.com` namespace, its child elements are not in any namespace.  Thus their namespace will need to be overridden using an [`XmlElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.
3. Setting the `XmlRoot` namespace will use the specified namespace as the default namespace.  If you must use a prefixed namespace, you need to pass a `XmlSerializerNamespaces` with all desired namespaces to [`XmlSerializer.Serialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z5zfc6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Thus:

```
[XmlRoot("MT_Get_Name_Req", Namespace = Employee.XmlNamespace)]
public class Employee
{
    public const string XmlNamespace = "http://hsd.sd.com";
    public const string XmlNamespacePrefix = "ns0";

    const string xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    const string xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlSerializerNamespaces
    {
        get
        {
            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(XmlNamespacePrefix, XmlNamespace);
            // namespaces.Add("xsi", xsi);  Uncomment to add standard namespaces.
            // namespaces.Add("xsd", xsd);
            return namespaces;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("personnel_id", Namespace="")]
    public string personnel_id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("dob", Namespace = "")]
    public string dob { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like

```
        var xml = XmlSerializationHelper.GetXml(employee, Employee.XmlSerializerNamespaces, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Using the extension methods:

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public sealed class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
    {
        private readonly Encoding encoding;

        public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding)
        {
            this.encoding = encoding;
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return encoding; }
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns, Encoding encoding)
    {
        return GetXml(obj, new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()), ns, encoding);
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns, Encoding encoding)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding(encoding))
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;        // For cosmetic purposes.
            settings.IndentChars = "    "; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                if (ns != null)
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
                else
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req xmlns:ns0="http://hsd.sd.com">
    <personnel_id>1202</personnel_id>
    <dob>19470906</dob>
</ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - just tested and This doesn't spit out the required XML - it adds the W#schools thing to the header and also adds NS0 to all the nodes

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req xmlns:ns0="http://hsd.sd.com">
    <ns0:personnel_id>1202</ns0:personnel_id>
    <ns0:dob>19470906</ns0:dob>
</ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req>

 is what i get after removing the w3schools

Comment: @jordan.peoples - I missed the fact that `personnel_id` and `dob` are in a different namespace than the root element.  Updated.

Comment: @jordan.peoples - `encoding="utf-16"` shows up because your writing to a string not a file, and c# strings are encoded in utf-16.  If you want to write to a string but force `utf-8` to appear as the encoding, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564718/using-stringwriter-for-xml-serialization/1564727#1564727

Comment: @jordan.peoples - 1) you mean the Jon Skeet solution didn't work?  2) Is everything else OK?

Comment: What i did to get your solution to run correctly, is simply call String.replace on your XML output to replace UTF-16 with UTF-8 and it worked like a charm

Comment: @jordan.peoples - I just tried the Skeet solution and it seems to work; I updated my answer with the appropriate code.  But string.Replace() should be fine also.

Comment: This feels like the super long confusing way to do it, but it did the trick, hacking together the correct XML.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small example for you. I included an **XmlRoot Attribute** to the *Employee.class* and added a **namespace object** when serializing the employee.

- see [Add prefixes and namespaces to xml Serialization](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ed55114-0f1b-4e54-b597-21fe1a61f06b/add-prefixes-and-namesapce-to-xml-serialization)
- and SO Question [How to set xml prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes)

**Employee.cs**

```
[XmlRoot("MT_Get_Name_Req", Namespace = "http://hsd.sd.com")]
public class Employee
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace="")]
    public string personnel_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string dob { get; set; }
}
```

**demoFile.cs**

```
private static void customXmlSerialization()
{
    Employee employee = new Employee() { personnel_id = "1202", dob = "19470906" };
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("ns0", "http://hsd.sd.com");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));

    string path = @"e:\temp\data.xml";
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(path, Encoding.UTF8);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, employee,ns);
}
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req xmlns:ns0="http://hsd.sd.com">
  <personnel_id>1202</personnel_id>
  <dob>19470906</dob>
</ns0:MT_Get_Name_Req>
```

Comment: I need the NSO on the MT_GET_NAME_REQ nodes, and also need UTF 8

Comment: And thank you for your answer, it is short and quick, just a little off

Comment: got it @jordan.peoples - see my updated answer, if you need text as stream/string let me know - or you can adapt it on your own!

Comment: This doesnt work at all.  here is the xml it gives: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><MT_Get_Name_Req xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://hsd.sd.com"><personnel_id xmlns="">1202</personnel_id><dob xmlns="">19470906</dob></MT_Get_Name_Req>

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you posted @jordan.peoples. I just rechecked my posted code. It exports the file as posted - pls recheck and see if this could check out for you.