# Windows App - Using XML in textbox

Tags: c#, xml, windows

```
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Cuisine { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
}


 public async static Task<RootObject> GetRecipe()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = String.Format("http://api.bigoven.com/recipe/196149?api_key=//apikey");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
        RootObject i;
        i = (RootObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return i;
    }
```

I use the above method in a bigoven class which gets the data of a recipe as XML data such as:

```
<Recipe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<RecipeID>196149</RecipeID>
<Title>Lasagna</Title>
<Cuisine>Italian</Cuisine>
```

and I would like to put the data for the title and cuisine into textboxes, however when I try the method below I get the error  "Recipe xmlns='' was not expected."

```
        RootObject myRecipe = await bigoven.GetRecipe();
        textBox.Text = myRecipe.Title;
```

Comment: Just curious, you say this data is being returned as XML, then why are you using a JSON serializer?

Comment: You might want to look into the XmlSerializer class.  Its Deserialize method takes a Stream and deserializes it into the Object of your choice.

Comment: I've changed it to use an XMLSerialiser but im getting the error: "<Recipe xmlns=''> was not expected."

Answer (score 0):

Answered before. Basically this:

*When serialising an XML document to a .NET string, the encoding must be set to UTF-16. Strings are stored as UTF-16 internally, so this is the only encoding that makes sense. If you want to store data in a different encoding, you use a byte array instead.*

See the entire thread here:

[Using StringWriter for XML Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564718/using-stringwriter-for-xml-serialization)

Comment: It looks like they are trying to deserialize xml data using a json serializer, hence the invalid "<" character. I'm not sure that's the same thing. They  may run into the encoding issue once they use an XmlSerializer, so this may be useful for a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Json `serializer` might be trying to deserialize xml data.

You might try looking at the raw string in `result` and making sure that it's actually JSON data. If it's not, you need to find the appropriate deserailizer to use.

I'm guessing `result` contains XML in which case you'd need to use an XML Deserializer to convert it to a `RootObject`

Here's the link for the .NET one:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I edited my method to try and use it however i get the message, "<Recipe xmlns=''> was not expected."

Comment: That's definitely XML data though, so I think you're on the right track.

Comment: result does contain xml as before, but even though I have changed my code to work like the example you provided it is more or less the same error.

Comment: Well RootObject doesn't contain a property called "Recipe" so the deserializer doesn't know what to do with that node. I don't think you can deserialize the results of that API call to the class you created. You may need to review the API return value and make sure the XML it is returning matches the class you are trying to populate.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to just call `XDocument.Parse` on the XML string you have and process the XML nodes the way you want. You don't actually have to deserialize it, you can manually process the return value. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse(v=vs.110).aspx