# How to serialize a document to XML without xmlns

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to serialize objects to XML. I'm having an issue that xsi and xsd are being added by default. I added the following code to remove the namespaces:

```
public string CommitDocumentToRepository(string extension, byte[] fileBytes)
{
    //Convert to PDF
    byte[] loPDFFileBytes;

    ConversionService.ContentResponse loResponse = new DocumentAdapter.ConversionService.ContentResponse();

    using (ConversionService.CustomPDFSoapClient loConversionServiceClient = new DocumentAdapter.ConversionService.CustomPDFSoapClient())
    {
        loResponse = loConversionServiceClient.OfficeToPDFContent(fileBytes, extension);
        loPDFFileBytes = loResponse.ContentPDF;
    }

    if (loPDFFileBytes != null)
    {
        xform loDocContainer = new xform();
        xformInstance loDocProperties = new xformInstance();

        loDocProperties.FIRST_NAME= this.FirstName;
        loDocProperties.LAST_NAME= this.LastName;
        loDocProperties.MID_NAME = this.MidName;


        loDocContainer.instance = loDocProperties;

        string lsTempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        string lsXMLofProperties = loDocContainer.Serialize();

        XmlDocument loDoc = new XmlDocument();


        loDoc.LoadXml(lsXMLofProperties);
        loDoc.Save(lsTempFile);

        byte[] loFilePropertiesXML = Common.StreamFile(lsTempFile);
        string lsReturnValue = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (ISCommittalService.CommittalSoapClient loCommittalServiceClient = new DocumentAdapter.ISCommittalService.CommittalSoapClient())
            {
                lsReturnValue = loCommittalServiceClient.CommitDocumentByte(loPDFFileBytes, ".PDF", loFilePropertiesXML);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception loException)
        {
            ADConnectionException loConnectionException = new ADConnectionException(loException);
            throw loException;
        }

        return lsReturnValue;
    }
    else
        return string.Empty;


}

 public string Serialize()
    {
       XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

       ns.Add("", "");

       XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
       xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
       xws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
       StringBuilder loBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());

       using (StringWriter loWriter = new StringWriter(loBuilder))
         {
            formatter.Serialize(loWriter, this,ns);
         }
       return loBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
  <xform>
    <instance>

    <FIRST_NAME xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    d3p1:type="q4:string" 
    xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">John</FIRST_NAME>

    <MID_NAME xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    d3p1:type="q3:string" xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>

    <LAST_NAME xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    d3p1:type="q5:string" 
    xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Doe</LAST_NAME>

    </instance>
   </xform>
```

How can I remove that added xmlns (`xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    d3p1:type="q4:string" 
    xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) from each object?
and how can I change it to utf-8 because `xws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`  that is my code seems doesn't have any affect.

Comment: Show us your c# classes.

Comment: .NET string have Unicode encoding (UTF-16). Serialize (save) xml directly to file with proper encoding.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I updated the post with c# class.
How can I save xml directly to file with utf-8?

Comment: You haven't added the classes. I'm going to guess that all your properties (e.g. `FIRST_NAME`) have the type `object`. Changing these to `string` will remove the type attributes.

Comment: @CharlesMager that worked properly. Thank you! How can I change utf-16 to utf-8 please? I use this code but it didn't change the encoding:  XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            xws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: You need to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564727/1320845).

Comment: @CharlesMager I tried that and I was getting an error "Root element is missing"