# Xml circular reference

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, circular-reference

I am trying to produce the following XML using the class structure below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<VirtualDesktopManager>
  <Categories>
    <Category Name="Category 1">
      <Desktops>
        <Desktop Name="Desktop 1">
          <Applications Name="Application 1" />
          <Applications Name="Application 2" />
        </Desktop>
      </Desktops>
    </Category>
  </Categories>
</VirtualDesktopManager>
```

When executing the code below, I get the exception: `System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot insert a node or any ancestor of that node as a child of itself.'`. The classes themselves do not have any circular references so I must be doing something wrong.

```
private static void Main ()
{
    var database = new Database();
    var category = new VirtualDesktopCategory();
    var desktop = new VirtualDesktop();
    var application = new VirtualDesktopApplication();

    category = new VirtualDesktopCategory() { Name = "Cat 1", };
    database.Categories.Add(category);
    desktop = new VirtualDesktop() { Name = "Desktop 1", };
    category.Desktops.Add(desktop);
    application = new VirtualDesktopApplication() { Name = "Application 1", };
    desktop.Applications.Add(application);
    application = new VirtualDesktopApplication() { Name = "Application 2", };
    desktop.Applications.Add(application);

    database.ToXmlDocument().InnerText.Dump();
}

public class Database
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public List<VirtualDesktopCategory> Categories { get; private set; } = new();

    public XmlDocument ToXmlDocument()
    {
        var document = new XmlDocument();
        var xml = $@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes"" ?><VirtualDesktopManager></VirtualDesktopManager>";

        document.LoadXml(xml);
        document.DocumentElement?.AppendChild(this.ToXmlElement(document, document.DocumentElement));

        return document;
    }

    public XmlElement ToXmlElement(XmlDocument document, XmlElement elementParent)
    {
        var elementCategories = document.CreateElement("Categories");

        elementParent.AppendChild(elementCategories);

        foreach (var category in this.Categories)
        {
            // System.ArgumentException: Cannot insert a node or any ancestor of that node as a child of itself.
            elementCategories.AppendChild(category.ToXmlElement(document, elementCategories));
        }

        return elementCategories;
    }
}

public class VirtualDesktopCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public List<VirtualDesktop> Desktops { get; private set; } = new();

    public XmlElement ToXmlElement(XmlDocument document, XmlElement elementParent)
    {
        var elementCategory = document.CreateElement("Category");
        var elementDesktops = document.CreateElement("Desktops");

        elementCategory.AppendAttribute(document, nameof(this.Name), this.Name);

        elementParent.AppendChild(elementCategory);
        elementCategory.AppendChild(elementDesktops);

        foreach (var desktop in this.Desktops)
        {
            elementDesktops.AppendChild(desktop.ToXmlElement(document, elementDesktops));
        }

        return elementCategory;
    }
}

public class VirtualDesktop
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public List<VirtualDesktopApplication> Applications { get; private set; } = new();

    public XmlElement ToXmlElement(XmlDocument document, XmlElement elementParent)
    {
        var elementDesktop = document.CreateElement("Desktop");
        var elementApplications = document.CreateElement("Applications");

        elementDesktop.AppendAttribute(document, nameof(this.Name), this.Name);

        elementParent.AppendChild(elementDesktop);
        elementDesktop.AppendChild(elementApplications);

        foreach (var application in this.Applications)
        {
            elementApplications.AppendChild(application.ToXmlElement(document, elementApplications));
        }

        return elementParent;
    }
}

public class VirtualDesktopApplication
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    public XmlElement ToXmlElement(XmlDocument document, XmlElement elementParent)
    {
        var elementApplication = document.CreateElement("Application");

        elementApplication.AppendAttribute(document, nameof(this.Name), this.Name);

        elementParent.AppendChild(elementApplication);

        return elementApplication;
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static XmlAttribute AppendAttribute(this XmlElement element, XmlDocument document, string name, string value)
    {
        var attribute = document.CreateAttribute(name);

        attribute.Value = value;
        element.Attributes.Append(attribute);

        return attribute;
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

Comment: Not particularly related, but any reason you're not using XmlSerializer? That would remove most of the boilerplate you have there

Comment: @canton7: Yes, this is just sample code but I need finer control over what gets written versus what gets read so attribute-based serialization is not a good fit for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class VirtualDesktop
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public List<VirtualDesktopApplication> Applications { get; private set; } = new();

    public XmlElement ToXmlElement(XmlDocument document, XmlElement elementParent)
    {
        var elementDesktop = document.CreateElement("Desktop");
        var elementApplications = document.CreateElement("Applications");

        elementDesktop.AppendAttribute(document, nameof(this.Name), this.Name);

        elementParent.AppendChild(elementDesktop);
        elementDesktop.AppendChild(elementApplications);

        foreach (var application in this.Applications)
        {
            elementApplications.AppendChild(application.ToXmlElement(document, elementApplications));
        }

        return elementParent;
    }
}
```

You're returning `elementParent`, rather than `elementDesktop`.

You had mis-identified the line throwing the exception. It was actually:

```
elementDesktops.AppendChild(desktop.ToXmlElement(document, elementDesktops));
```

So, something in `desktop.ToXmlElement` was the cause. A quick bit of trial-and-error shows that commenting out everything in `VirtualDesktop.ToXmlElement` doesn't fix it, so it's somewhere between the `var elementDesktop = document.CreateElement("Desktop")` and `return elementParent;`... Wait...

---

You're also serializing the XmlDocument incorrectly. You need to do something like:

```
using var sr = new StringWriter();
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sr))
{
    database.ToXmlDocument().Save(writer);
}
Console.WriteLine(sr.ToString());
```

However, this will give you:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
```

To fix the encoding, you'll need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564727/1086121

---

[Working example](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), with the duplicate lines [identified by @EyesShriveledToRaisins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76900334/1086121) commented out.

Comment: I knew it had to be a silly mistake. Indeed, the return of `elementParent` as you pointed out needs to be `elementDesktop`. Thank you!

Comment: @RaheelKhan, FWIW producing a *minimal* reproducible sample (as in [mcve]), by removing code until all that was left was the code to produce the exception, would have made the problem very obvious. I effectively did the same thing by commenting out lines, and found the problem in under a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to [canton7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76900328/22388001), look at how you handle the returned node of (some of) your `ToXmlElement` methods.

Inside those `ToXmlElement` methods, you add the node to be returned to the given parent element. Then, outside of these methods in the respective `foreach` loops, you add that node again to the parent element once more.

Comment: You're correct, but that doesn't seem to have any adverse effects on the generated XML, interestingly.

Comment: @canton7, true. I just checked the documentation for `AppendChild`, and it states "_If the newChild is already in the tree, it is removed from its original position and added to its target position._". So technically this has no adverse consequences as the node is added to the parent, then removed from it and then added to it again without other nodes being added/removed to the same parent inbetween. Still, this shows a design issue with the code in the question. I ponder now whether i should remove my answer or let it stay even though it doesn't really address the question...

Comment: I say leave it -- it adds useful info, and I've upvoted it

Comment: Thanks @EyesShriveledToRaisins. I say leave it and have upvoted it too.